# How to build a no install, client-side only, database web app

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web-applications, nosql

Where I work it is pretty restricted in terms of IT.
I do not have access to an SQL Server or a Web server so things like Apache, PHP, mySQL etc are all off the table. No server side anything.
The PCs on the network cannot see each other (so installing WAMP and opening firewall ports wouldnt work...besides...we cant install anything either...all locked down), this is due to group policy restrictions. However there are plenty of shared drives that we all can use. Currently we are getting by using Microsoft Access but it is clunky.
We need to move towards tablets so managers can see info as they walk around. My building is a massive warehouse, hence the driver for the solution im trying to build.

So the question is this. I want to build a web app that displays KPIs/reports. It will need to have some type of database behind it so I can store data in which I can then retrieve via Javascript or something similar (remember I can only use client-side technolgies). Whether that's JSON or XML i dont really mind.
Multiple people will need access at the same time.

So to sum up

Can't install anything
No access to a web server or anything that resembles a web server
Do have shared drives so could store a NoSQL/JSON/XML file to share there
**Client-side technologies only**
PCs on the network cannot see each other
Cannot use any internet or cloud storage solutions as they are blocked

Im completely lost, any solutions?

Comment: That is a *really bad* situation. I would recommend SQLite, but one person could just hold a lock on that forever – a concern?

Comment: Yes, really bad. Im trying to get access to a SQL server but there are political roadblocks galore. As far as record locking, the users will be mostly reading from the db, not many writes/edits.

Comment: Go to your boss and tell him that your project is impossible under these conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out PouchDB.  http://pouchdb.com/

Pure Javascript and stores the data locally on the users machine.

In the future if you ever wanted to connect it to a server side database, you can connect it to CouchDB.

Comment: Have you ever used pouchdb locally? Do you just save a JSON file on local harddrive?

Comment: I've used CouchDB a fair amount, but never Pouch. I've just come across it in reading and being around Couch. I would imagine it just saves the JSON locally though.

Comment: I am not sure this answers the original question.
Just like OP, I would like to store a JSON on the server and query it like if it was a database. It's not clear whether PouchDB offers that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would implement in your situation:

Backbone.js with
https://www.stackmob.com/

Backbone provides a great way to build a robust client side app, and stackmob can host your db, here is a free tutorial:

https://www.udemy.com/learn-backbonejs-stackmob/

Comment: Unfortunately since stackmob is a cloud service I cannot use it. It is blocked, just like google drive and gmail and hotmail etc. The db needs to be local on the share drive.

Comment: Since you have the shared drive, you could put Mongo DB on that, and use that with Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite.org is a self contained, serverless, database

Comment: Are you able to communicate with it with Javascript only? It seems from the sqlite.org website you need to use C/C++?

Comment: JavaScript is a client side language,

Comment: Yes I know. That's the whole point of the question. There can be no server side anything in this solution. I do not have access to a server.