# Any technology for client-side read-only relational database framework?

Tags: javascript, database, html, client-side

I am implementing an HTML5 web client which loads an XML file containing a list of inter-related quantities, such as

```
<person>
    <name>Aviendha</name>
    <weapon>Spear</weapon><!-- Foreign key would go here -->
</person>
...
<weapon>
    <name>Spear</name>
    <color>Black</color>
</weapon>
```

I now face the "Should I include a relational database in my technology stack?" question, but the project I'm working on is limited in resources and infrastructure: I cannot install any SQL/noSQL server/service.

I'm looking for a framework that would allow me to:

1. Modify the XML (or JSON or any other standard) server-side, by the person in charge of it, with some software that will create relations between objects.
2. Fetch the XML/JSON file via jquery/javascript, unwrap it with an ad-hoc library, access objects and relations.
3. The XML/JSON cannot be changed by the user.

I know this is a very bizarre request, but the XML file will stay small and only served internally (I don't care if someone can read its whole content).
I also know that it's slow, non-scalable and hard to maintain.

There are a few similar question around, but none address this exact scope.
[This one gets close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848140/how-to-build-a-no-install-client-side-only-database-web-app) , but I can serve data through Apache.

Comment: To clarify: are you looking for a tool to help you with step 1.: modification of data and exporting to a static file to be uploaded to the server, or step 2./3.: read only storage on the client-side after the data has been fetched?